# Use different View Resolver for each Portlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portlet

Is it possible to configure different view resolvers (all of them of the type JstlView) for different portlets? My JSP directory structure looks like this:

```
+- WEB-INF
   |
   +- jsp
       |
       +- myorder
       |   |
       |   |- summary.jsp
       |   |
       |   |- edit-order.jsp
       |
       +- mydetails
       |   |
       |   |- summary.jsp
       |   |
       |   |- edit-details.jsp
       |
       |- error.jsp
       |
       |- success.jsp
```

(*generated using [treegen](http://www.adarshr.com/treegen)*)

I have a `common.xml` for the common application context and one each for the portlets (`mydetails-portlet.xml`, `myorder-portlet.xml`).

I also have a few common JSPs which can be invoked from any portlet (`error.jsp`, `success.jsp`).

The `viewResolver` definition inside `common.xml` looks like:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>
```

The `viewResolver` definition inside `mydetails-portlet.xml` looks like:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/mydetails/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

And I am expecting to invoke `error.jsp` and `edit-details.jsp` using the following lines inside the `@RequestMapping` controller method of say, mydetails-portlet:

```
return "error";
return "edit-details";
```

But having multiple definitions of `viewResolver` for `JstlView` seems to override the older ones and I eventually end up with the one that gets loaded last. As a result of this, I am not able to correctly resolve my views.

Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do, without resorting to hardcoded paths such as `return "mydetails/edit-details"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved this by extending the `InternalResourceViewResolver`. The logic behind this is simple. Because of the nature of `InternalResourceViewResolver`, we can't really chain it with another IRVR unless we have only one IRVR and it appears at the end of the chain.

So, we have to tell spring to `return null` when resolving views based on some condition which would cause the next IRVR in the chain to kick in.

To do this, all I did was extend the IRVR and used a pre-configured `excludePrefix` which if exists in the view name, my IRVR would exclude it and cause the chaining to take place.

Here is how my `ExcludingInternalResourceViewResolver` looks like:

```
public class ExcludingInternalResourceViewResolver extends
        InternalResourceViewResolver {

    private String excludePrefix;

    @Override
    public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale)
            throws Exception {

        if (this.excludePrefix != null && viewName.startsWith(this.excludePrefix)) {
            return null;
        }

        return super.resolveViewName(viewName, locale);
    }

    public void setExcludePrefix(String excludePrefix) {
        this.excludePrefix = excludePrefix;
    }
}
```

Well, basically I have two sets of view resolvers configured. One of them is the common one for handling error, success pages whose declaration looks like:

```
<bean id="commonViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="3" />
</bean>
```

The other one which goes inside each portlet looks like:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="com.foo.common.spring.web.view.ExcludingInternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/mydetails/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="excludePrefix" value="common" />
</bean>
```

My error handler looks like:

```
<bean id="defaultExceptionHandler" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="common/error" />
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="javax.portlet.PortletException">common/portlet-error</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And lastly, I moved my `error.jsp` and `portlet-error.jsp` from `/WEB-INF/jsp/` to `/WEB-INF/jsp/common/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the resource bundle instead of the xml files. This worked for me.

For that you would need to contain a bundle file `any_name.properties` file having your views declared as below, e.g.

I have the following portlet jsp files

*WEB-INF/jsp/flight/bookingForm.jsp 

WEB-INF/jsp/flight/bookingSuccess.jsp

WEB-INF/jsp/appError.jsp*

Contents of **any_name.properties** file are as below. Please observe that the view names are followed by `.(class)` and `.url` in the declaration.

---

```
bookingForm.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
bookingForm.url=/WEB-INF/jsp/flight/bookingForm.jsp

bookingSuccess.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
bookingSuccess.url=/WEB-INF/jsp/flight/bookingSuccess.jsp
```

---

This any_name.properties bundle has to be integrated in your *appView-portlet.xml* configuration file (assuming you have **appView** portlet declared in your portlet.xml).

**If you have placed the any_name.properties in the *com.module.views* package**, then you would need to configure as below.

```
<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
       <property name="basenames">
          <list>
         <value>com.module.views.any_name</value>
           </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

For the appError.jsp, you can have the default view resolver, if any, declared in your applicationContext.xml file.

```
<!-- Default View Resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. spring-mvc provides convention over configuration. Read [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-coc) article. It will help you to understand concept of coc. Different jsp pages from different folders can be used as per requirement.